# ngClass angular with field logic as param

Tags: angular, angular5

i want to create dynamic class on field change not on form submitted
the problem i have no idea to make it true :D please help me

this is my component html

```
 <div [ngClass]="formGroup">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required (ngModel)]="model.name" name="name" #name="ngModel">

</div>
```

this is my ts

```
formGroup = {
    'form-group': true,
    'has-error': heroForm.name.invalid
  }
```

Comment: Could you please add more details as to on what condition which class needs to be added?

Comment: the condition base on this
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name" #name="ngModel">

Answer (score 1):

i got the answer
actually i dont need to get the ngClass value from my .ts
i can directly set the value by inlining it

```
<div [ngClass]="{'form-group': true, 'has-error': name.invalid}">
```

thank you, have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2**

If you want to be able to add more than one class using your logic, you could use  [ngClass] like below..

```
<button class='originalClass' [ngClass]='getSomeMoreClasses()'>Button</button>
```

And in your component...

```
export class YourAppComponent {
    applyClass1: boolean = true;
    applyClass2: boolean = true;
    applyClass3: boolean = true;

    getSomeMoreClasses() {
        let classes = {
            class1: this.applyClass1,
            class2: this.applyClass2,
            class3: this.applyClass3
        };

        return classes;
    }
}
```

**Update 1**

If you already have some classes applied, and want to add more classes to the element...

E.g.,

HTML element with original class 'originalClass' and more classes defined in component:

```
<button class='originalClass' [class]='someMoreClasses'>My Button</button>
```

And in your component class:

```
export class YourAppComponent {
    someMoreClasses: string = 'additionalClass1 additionalClass2';
}
```

This will end up rendering your element with 3 classes - 1 original and 2 from the component class.

**Original answer:**

Check this stackblitz out - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ozcecx

html:

```
<h1 [class.coolClass]="boolVar">H1 element</h1>
<button (click)="toggleClass()">Toggle Class</button>
```

ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  boolVar: boolean = false;

  toggleClass(): void {
    this.boolVar = !this.boolVar;
  }

}
```

css:

```
.coolClass{
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: angular will ignore (not render) html atribute class if class directive used. i need to add many class to an element which one of the class base on the input valid or not

Comment: do you want to display an error like 'input is required' or something when user loses focus from the field? What do you mean by create dynamic class on field change?

Comment: <div class="form-group" [class]="moreclass">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name" #name="ngModel">
      <!-- <p class="hint">remove this {{model.name}}</p> -->
      <!-- <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">Name is requried</div> -->
    </div>

if the field invalid i want to add class has-error to the .form-group

Comment: Btw, are you using bootstrap 3 or 4? I have used bootstrap 4 in that stackblitz.

Comment: i dont get it yet... before i submit the form... how can i catch the field is valid or invaldi (onchange)? so i can add it to my var moreclass = { iserror = name.valid }

Comment: @RickyOrlandoNapitupulu did you have a look at the stackblitz? `*ngIf="name.touched && name.invalid"` looks after that, 
`name.touched` bit checks if the user has lost the focus from the field and `name.invalid` will be true if the required field does not have any value. Hence, `*ngIf="name.touched && name.invalid"` will check if the user selected and left the required field without typing anything in, and it does not have anything to do with form submit. Does it help?